# How to detect changes set by adb setprop during run time in C++

Tags: android, c++

I have set a property using **adb setprop**. While my app is running, if the user dynamically updates the property value I want to detect and change the behaviour of my app based on the new value.

I use properties.h --> property_get function to get the value everytime the code executes whether the value has changed or not.

I do not want to keep reading the property file everytime tough - i want to react only on a change.
Is there a way to achieve this using C++?